# No speedup using asyncio despite awaiting API response

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am running a program that makes three different requests from a rest api. data, indicator, request functions all fetch data from BitMEX's api using a wrapper i've made.

I have used asyncio to try to speed up the process so that while i am waiting on a response from previous request, it can begin to make another one.

However, my asynchronous version is not running any quicker for some reason. The code works and as far as I know, I have set everything up correctly. But there could be something  wrong with how I am setting up the coroutines?

Here is the asynchronous version:

```
import time
import asyncio

from bordemwrapper import BitMEXData, BitMEXFunctions


'''
asynchronous I/O
'''

async def data():
    data = BitMEXData().get_ohlcv(symbol='XBTUSD', timeframe='1h', 
                                  instances=25)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return data

async def indicator():
    indicator = BitMEXData().get_indicator(symbol='XBTUSD', 
        timeframe='1h', indicator='RSI', period=20, source='close', 
        instances=25)
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return indicator

async def request():
    request = BitMEXFunctions().get_price()
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    return request

async def chain():
    data_ = await data()
    indicator_ = await indicator()
    request_ = await request()
    return data_, indicator_, request_

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(chain())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    asyncio.run(main())
    end = time.perf_counter()

    print('process finished in {} seconds'.format(end - start))
```

Comment: In addition to Josh's response, your `chain` coroutine is written to await the three downloads **in sequence**. Even if they were using asyncio correctly, you would get sequential downloading. To fix this (after switching to actually using asyncio as indicated by Josh), `chain` needs to await `gather(data(), indicator(), request()`, and only **then** will the three run in parallel. Calling `gather` with a single coroutine, as done in `main()` serves no purpose and is equivalent to just awaiting the coroutine directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, `asyncio` isn't magic. Although you've put them in `async` functions, the `BitMEXData().get_<foo>` functions are not themselves async (i.e. you can't `await` them), and therefore block while they run. The concurrency in `asyncio` can only occur while `await`ing something.

You'll need a library which makes the actual HTTP requests asynchronously, like [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It sounds like you wrote `bordemwrapper` yourself - you should rewrite the `get_<foo>` functions to use asynchronous HTTP requests. Feel free to submit a separate question if you need help with that.

Comment: ah yes, i see now. been reading the aiohttp docs and going to try it out, thanks so much for your help